# POST/PUT response REST in a CQRS/ES system

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, saga

I'm implementing a CQRS/ES based system with a RESTful interface which is used by a webapp.

When performing certain actions e.g. creating a new profile I need to be able to check certain conditions, such as uniqueness of the profile ID, or that the person has the right to create a resource under a group. Which means I have a couple of options:

Context: `POST/profiles { "email": "unique@example.com" }`

1. From my REST API return `202` from my service with a location of the new resource where my client can poll for it. In this case, however, how do I handle errors as in effect the view will not exist or ever exist.
2. Create a saga on the initial request then dispatch the event. Once my service creates the view or finds the error then the result is written to the saga. When the saga has been completed return the result to the user.

From these two options - the second seems more reasonable to me, if not more complex. Is this a viable option for building RESTful request/response models on a CQRS/ES event sourced backend?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the second solution seems to better fit the business.

From what I understand from your case, from the [DDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) point of view, the creation of a user profile is a business process, with more than one steps (verifying the uniqueness of the profile, creating the profile and recovering from a duplicate profile situation). This process acts like an entity, it starts, runs and ends with a result (success or error). Being an entity it has an ID and it can be viewed as a REST resource. A Saga will be responsible for executing it.

So, in response to the client's request you send the URI of the process resource where the client can poll for the status. In case of error, it reads the error message. In case of success, it gets the URI of its profile.

The first solution can still be used if the use-case is simpler, if the command can be executed synchronously and the client gets the final result (error or success) as an immediate response.

Answer (score 1):

> From my REST API return 202 from my service with a location of the new resource where my client can poll for it. In this case, however, how do I handle errors as in effect the view will not exist or ever exist.

The usual answer here is that, as part of the [202 Accepted](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.3) response, you include monitoring information

> The representation sent with this response ought to describe the request's current status and point to (or embed) a status monitor that can provide the user with an estimate of when the request will be fulfilled.

In other words, a link to a resource that will change when the accepted request is finally run.

So in describing the protocol, in addition to the resource that you create, you'll also need to document the representation used when you defer the work for later, and the representation used by the monitor.

> When the saga has been completed return the result to the user.

Depending on the work, that may be overkill.

Which is to say, you are raising two different questions here; one of those is whether the request should be handled synchronously (don't respond until the work is done) or asynchronously (return right away, but give the client the means to monitor progress).

The other question is how the work looks from the business layer.  If you are going to need multiple transactions to make the change, and if you may need to "revert" previously committed transactions in some variants of the process, then a saga (or a [process manager](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/ProcessManager.html)) makes sense.

[Set Validation](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/08/12/eventual-consistency-and-set-validation/) -- the broader term for enforcing an invariant like "uniqueness" -- is awkward.  Make sure you study, and ensure that you and the business understand the impact of having a failure.